# Mongo document to enforce strict datatype using bsons

Tags: java, mongodb, bson, mongodb-update

I have a codebase in which we have widely been using Bson document to persist / update documents in multiple collections. Whilst mongodb gives us the flexibility to add attributes and extend as required, we want a specific attribute in a collection to be stored in a particular type. 
For example,

```
Long longValue = 1L;
Document doc = new Document();
doc.append("attribute1", longValue);
```

//Persist the documenent in the collection.
//Some lines of the code and in another module the same document for the same collection is modified as below -

```
Double doubleValue = 2L;
doc.append("attribute1", doubleValue);
```

Is there anyway to avoid this, since the persistence of this document in both sections of the code will not result in an exception?

Comment: MongoDB itself is "schemaless", and this is usually one of the main attractions. If you want to enforce schema rules, then "usually" that's the domain of your business logic to ensure that in the code you write, and optionally with "class mappers" if you are using that sort of thing. There is ["schema validation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/), but even though that's been in for a few releases now, it's really should be viewed as "experimental". Enforcing this really is the domain of the business logic in your code.

Comment: Note I say "experimental' largely because reported errors from "schema validation" are "rudimentary" at best. There are plenty of object mapping frameworks which offer "much more" than what features that provides.